# How to read cross domain GET response?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I know this has been discussed a lot on this site and others but I am still unable to read the response from cross domain GET request.

I am testing a website that responds with a CSRF token when a GET request https://domain/csrf-token/ is sent to the site. The site has has a comprehensive CSP policy and responds with token for following request:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}

var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('https://domain/csrf-token/', function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even though the request is successful the script is unable to read the response contents. I believe this is because of my limited understanding of CSP policy directives. The site I am testing has a comprehensive CSP policy and based on my research following directives are relevant to my scenario:

1. default-src 'self' cdn.example.com (The default-src is the default policy for loading content such as JavaScript, Images, CSS, Fonts, AJAX requests, Frames, HTML5 Media.
2. script-src  'self' js.example.com   (Defines valid sources of JavaScript.)
3. connect-src 'self'  (Applies to XMLHttpRequest (AJAX), WebSocket or EventSource.)

However, I am not sure which directive is applicable for cross-domain GET request generated via javascript. Can you please help me understand?

I have uploaded the above code in test.html file on AWS cloudfront as CSP states:
connect-src 'self' 'self' *.cloudfront.net

**HTTP GET request:**

```
GET /csrf-token/ HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: https://*.amazonaws.com/test.html
Origin: https://*.amazonaws.com
Connection: close
```

**HTTP response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: *****
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 05:20:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
x-csrf-token: 1******825-01-RDDOhp****csrf-token
Set-Cookie: ****************************** cookie
X-xcustomheader-xxx: xxx-frontend
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 57

1******825-01-RDDOhp****csrf-token
```

Please note that no headers are sent to server that block cross-domain requests:

Appreciate your patience considering I am beginner on cross-domain requests. Also, do provide any links that may help me understand the concepts much better.

Comment: Your server should send a response header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`. This will allow the server to take cross-domain request.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna So if that header is not present in response there is no way to read the token?

Comment: @AJINKYA https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS is probably the best place to start reading up on this, but yeah the gist of it is, if the server doesn’t send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in the response, then your browser will block your frontend JavaScript code from having any access to the response.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and the link.